# Where can I find an Attrazione?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

This car is supposedly the fastest in the game. Does it have any dedicated spawn locations, or are they completely random? Where are the best places in which to find an [Attrazione](http://www.forvo.com/word/attrazione/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Attrazione#Saints_Row:_The_Third) they will spawn randomly by civilians and have no know spot where they spawn. You'll have to be patient and lucky to find one.

Comment: fwiw I found my outside the garage of the first safe house within minutes of starting my game, so it is pretty much pure luck

Answer (score 1):

Try New Baranec.

I found a majority of my Attrazione there.

Answer (score -1):

I had an attrazione and for some reason I lost it when i was driving it and started the mission for murder brawl 31... the location is usually random, though I find the easiest way to find one is to spend a while on the free way or in any places that seem to have the more fast/expensive cars (near the saints hq is one of the places you may find one)... hope this helps :)

Answer (score -2):

I found an attrazione outside the saints hq. Hang out there for a while and you will find one.
It took me about 7-10 min to do so.